# What is the difference between 2 regex patterns?

Tags: php, regex

I want users input their username with only alphanumeric and dot character.
So I wrote a regex pattern as following:

```
'/([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)/'
```

But I want to know is it the same with:

```
'/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/'
```

2 below patterns is the same? Thank you for help! :-)

Comment: As far as i know it's the same since you don't have to escape a dot!

Comment: You don't need to use capturing groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape the dot which was present inside a character class. Inside a character class, dot `.` and escaped dot `\.` matches the literal dot. So both regexes are same.

And also for validation purposes, i would suggest you to add anchors like `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/'` . Anchors would be used to do a exact string  match. That is , `/[a-zA-Z0-9.]+/` regex would match the substring `foo` in this `()foo` input string but if you add start and end anchors to your regex like `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/`, it won't match even a single character in the above mentioned string. It's allowed to match only one or more alphanumeric or dot characters , if it finds a character other than dot or alphanumeric, then the regex engine won't match the corresponding string.

Comment: Regex Master :D +1! Very nice answer

Comment: @AvinashRaj I got it wrong, thought the answer was incorrect. I removed the downvote, my fault.